# Google Motion Chart: Stopping Interpolation / Any Alternative?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Wonder if anyone can help. I've got a couple of questions re: the Google Motion Chart:

1. Does anyone know how to stop it interpolating data? E.g. currently if have data for 2006,2007, NOT 2008, but yes have data for 2009, 2010, etc .. - it interpolates the data and plots it. Aaaagh. Anyone know how to stop it doing this?
2. Does anyone know of any alternative motion type chart?

Many thanks,

Comment: Have you found a solution?? I need to avoid interpolating... I have data for every 1st of the month... 01jan, 01feb, 01mar.. and so on for 6 years... I want the time to run without going through every date inbetween.. and without interpolation. so 01jan 100, 01feb 250... then graph should jump from 100 to 250.. when the time frame changes from 01jan to 01feb.. hope you understand...? any alternatives.